# Emacs / Wanderlust / OSX -- Any ideas what could cause Emacs to acquire focus when using Wanderlust?

Tags: emacs

I'm using Wanderlust with Emacs on OSX 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) and frequently switch to a different application while Wanderlust is prefetching e-mails and organizing the summary buffers.  At several stages during this process, Emacs acquires focus and steels me away from whatever I was doing in another application.  I don't think Wanderlust has any built-in applescripts and I haven't added any, so I have no idea what could be causing Emacs to demand focus.  Any ideas how to leave Emacs in the background while updating Wanderlust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular circumstance, I had modified `wl-summary-get-buffer-create` to use a custom made `display-buffer` function ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/18371427/2112489 ).  When that function was executed, Emacs acquired focus on OSX 10.6.8 (after having been back-grounded).

The function `wl-summary-goto-folder-subr` can take a substantial amount of time to complete depending upon various factors and user settings, and this function also uses `wl-summary-get-buffer-create`.

If Emacs mysteriously acquires focus after having been back-grounded, look for the usage of functions such as `display-buffer` and `select-window` and `set-window-buffer` and special functions like `switch-to-frame`:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17824173/2112489  The most likely suspects are:  `select-frame-set-input-focus`, which contains functions like:  `x-focus-frame`, `raise-frame`, `select-frame`.